# Lookup on two values

Tags: excel, match, vlookup

I'm trying to check if two values exist side by side each other.

on one sheet I have:

```
Country     Language
UK          EN
UK          DE
UK          ES
```

And on another sheet I have the same.

What I need to do is make sure UK and EN match in the second sheet's version.

atm I've been trying something like `=VLOOKUP(B2, Sheet1!$A$1:$H$230, MATCH(Sheet2!C2, Sheet1!$D$1:$D$230, 0), FALSE)`

But no luck on my end.

Can anyone help me out here.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to reurn the value, or just, true, false? If a true false is what you need, try the COUNTIFS function (Excel >= 2007)

Comment: just a true or false will suffice, I'll take a look into COUNTIF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need a True False outcome, u can use COUNTIFS

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4;A2;Sheet1!$B$2:$B$4;B2)
```

For Excel 2003 and older use

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4;A2)*COUNTIF(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$4;B2)
```

This will return the number of hits, if you just want TRUE or FALSE wrap it like:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4;A2;Sheet1!$B$2:$B$4;B2) > 0
```

Comment: Sorry but it's not outputting correct results, I'm using `=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$C$2:$D$230, Sheet2!B2, Sheet1!$C$2:$D$230, Sheet2!C2)` and it's returning 0 when it should return a value greater

Comment: You should refer to 1 column at a time: $C$2:$C$230, not $C$2:$D$230